# Including minutes column in CSV breaks date parsing

Tags: python, pandas, csv

##### Problem

I have a CSV file with components of the date and time in separate columns. When I use `pandas.read_csv`, I can use the `parse_date` kwarg to combine the components into a single datetime column *if I don't include the minutes column*.

##### Example

Consider the following example:

```py
from io import StringIO

import pandas 

data = """\
GAUGE,YEAR,MONTH,DAY,HOUR,MINUTE,PRECIP
1,2008,03,27,19,30,0.02
1,2008,03,27,19,45,0.06
1,2008,03,27,20,0,0.01
1,2008,03,27,20,30,0.01
1,2008,03,27,21,0,0.12
1,2008,03,27,21,15,0.02
1,2008,03,27,23,15,0.02
1,2008,03,27,23,30,0.01
1,2008,03,30,04,0,0.05
1,2008,03,30,04,15,0.24
"""

df_has_dt = pandas.read_csv(
    StringIO(data),
    parse_dates={'datetime': ['YEAR', 'MONTH', 'DAY', 'HOUR']},
)

df_no_dt = pandas.read_csv(
    StringIO(data),
    parse_dates={'datetime': ['YEAR', 'MONTH', 'DAY', 'HOUR', 'MINUTE']},
)
```

If I look at the `.info()` method of each dataframe, I get:

The first:

```
RangeIndex: 10 entries, 0 to 9
Data columns (total 4 columns):
 #   Column    Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------    --------------  -----         
 0   datetime  10 non-null     datetime64[ns]  # <--- good, but doesn't have minutes of course
 1   GAUGE     10 non-null     int64         
 2   MINUTE    10 non-null     int64         
 3   PRECIP    10 non-null     float64
```

The second:

```
RangeIndex: 10 entries, 0 to 9
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column    Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------    --------------  -----  
 0   datetime  10 non-null     object  # <--- bad!
 1   GAUGE     10 non-null     int64  
 2   PRECIP    10 non-null     float64
```

Indeed, `df_no_dt.head()` shows a very strange "datetime" column:

```
        datetime  GAUGE  PRECIP
2008 03 27 19 30      1    0.02
2008 03 27 19 45      1    0.06
 2008 03 27 20 0      1    0.01
2008 03 27 20 30      1    0.01
 2008 03 27 21 0      1    0.12
```

##### Question:

What's causing this and how should I efficiently get the minutes of the time into the datetime column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why just adding on the `minutes` column for datetime parsing isn't working. But you can specify a function to parse them like so:

```py
from io import StringIO

import pandas

data = """\
GAUGE,YEAR,MONTH,DAY,HOUR,MINUTE,PRECIP
1,2008,03,27,19,30,0.02
1,2008,03,27,19,45,0.06
1,2008,03,27,20,0,0.01
1,2008,03,27,20,30,0.01
1,2008,03,27,21,0,0.12
1,2008,03,27,21,15,0.02
1,2008,03,27,23,15,0.02
1,2008,03,27,23,30,0.01
1,2008,03,30,04,0,0.05
1,2008,03,30,04,15,0.24
"""

DT_COLS = ['YEAR', 'MONTH', 'DAY', 'HOUR', 'MINUTE']

def dt_parser(*args):
    return pandas.to_datetime(pandas.DataFrame(zip(*args), columns=DT_COLS))

df = pandas.read_csv(
    StringIO(data),
    parse_dates={'datetime': DT_COLS},
    date_parser=dt_parser,
)
```

Which outputs:

```py
>>> df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 10 entries, 0 to 9
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column    Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------    --------------  -----         
 0   datetime  10 non-null     datetime64[ns]
 1   GAUGE     10 non-null     int64         
 2   PRECIP    10 non-null     float64       
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(1), int64(1)
memory usage: 368.0 bytes
```

---

How `dt_parser` works. It relies on an feature of [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) that can recognise common names for date/time types. These aren't fully documented, but at the time of writing they can be found [in the pandas source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/ef9944376311de52a2394b489ef1d73782c1a8de/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py#L923-L945). They all are:

```py
"year", "years",
"month", "months",
"day", "days",
"hour", "hours",
"minute", "minutes",
"second", "seconds",
"ms", "millisecond", "milliseconds",
"us", "microsecond", "microseconds",
"ns", "nanosecond", "nanoseconds",
```

Comment: Thanks, Alex. There's a deleted answer from @VinayakSingla that mentioned that the hours column is a two-digit number (e.g., 04 for 4am), but the minutes column is not. That appears to be the *why* including minutes fails. I like this answer as the workaround that handles my data as-is.

Comment: @PaulH interestingly dropping the preceding `0` from hour stops the parser working, but adding in the zeroes in the minutes column doesn't enable it. I've added a small explanation of how `dt_parser` works.